# Please help me with this doubt from spherical waves

Tags: waves, spherical-harmonics

How to calculate phase difference for spherical waves?
How to say whether they are in phase or out of phase?
In sinusoidal we can easily say whether they are in phase or out of phase just by looking at it,but how to do the same for spherical waves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spherical coordinates, you can write a spherical wave as $F(x,t) = A \exp (ikr - i\omega t)$. To say that two spherical waves are in phase at a certain point $(x,t)$ in space and time is to say that at this particular point, the argument inside the exponential is the same for both of them, up to a $2 \pi$ phase factor.

Imagine you have two sources that emit spherical waves of wavelenght $\lambda$, the sources are located at point $A$ and $B$, respectively. Let us denote by $\phi_0$ the constant phase shift between the two sources (which is to say, in the case of sinusoidal waves, one of them is $\cos(\omega t)$ and the other is $\cos (\omega t + \phi0)$).

Let us look at a point $M$ in space. We call $D_A$ the distance between $M$ and $A$ and $D_B$ the distance between $M$ and $B$. The two spherical waves are in phase at point $M$ under the condition that

$\frac{2 \pi}{\lambda} D_A = \frac{2 \pi}{\lambda} D_B + \phi_0$

This formula comes from the statement I made earlier : looking at a certain point $M$ at time $t$, the argument of the two waves must the same for both of them, up to a $2 \pi$ phase factor.

Comment: sir,please provide a simple explanation,iam still in high school

Comment: Ok, I'm editing my post.

Comment: thank you,please provide real life examples,which are much more easy to understand.i just wish to understand it and vsualize it,please don't use complicated equation.

Comment: Unfortunately, things such as the phase of waves is pretty abstract and won't be crystal clear to you until you do some calculations and see it in different contexts. But do not worry, every physicist has been there and your understanding of it will get better as you work with it

Answer (score 2):

From the center measure out any direction to a certain radius and all the waves at that distance will be at the same phase somewhere between a positive or negative amplitude.

Comment: so does a source emit sinusoidal waves in all direction?

Comment: if we say that 2 spherical waves are in phase at a point does that mean the waves which join that point to 2 centres are in phase?

Comment: As long as their the same frequency.

Comment: can i visualize in phase oscialltion, as two swings swinging identically with same frequency,amplitude and start from their mean position simulatenously?